# Ĉu -io estas sufikso?

Tags: word-formation

Nu, *-i-* ja estas produkta sufikso en nia lingvo, almenaŭ "eks-sufikso", ekz. oni formas landnomojn, kiel *Francio*, *Germanio*, ktp.

Sed la sufikso ne estas disigebla: "io" ne signifas *lando* kaj "ia" ne signifas *nacia*, do kiel ĝi estas sufikso se ĝin oni ne povas disigi? Ĉiujn aliajn sufiksojn oni povas disigi.

Answer (score 3):

Mi pensas, ke ĝi ja estas sufikso. Ke oni ne uzas ĝin memstare kun la sama signifo, ne implicas, ke ĝi ne estas sufikso. Ankaŭ *-uj-* ni uzas por formi landnomojn el la nomo de la popolo, dum *ujo* kaj *uja* neniam signifas *lando* aŭ *nacia* respektive.

Kvankam ili estas apartaj, ankaŭ *-ĉj-* kaj *-nj-* estas sufiksoj, dum oni ne uzas ilin memstare.

Estas aliaj, neoficialaj sufiksoj, kiuj ankaŭ ne estas memstare uzeblaj. Ekzemple, *-it-* estas sufikso, kiun oni uzas por formi inflamon de la korpoparto, kiun esprimas la radiko (ekz. hepato → hepatito). Tamen *ito* ne signifas *inflamo*.

---

REDAKTO:
Fakte, la participaj vorteroj *-i(n)t-*, *-a(n)t-*, *-o(n)t-* ankaŭ estas sufiksoj—antaŭe mi misdiris, ke ili estas finaĵoj; tamen oni ne povas fini vorton per tiuj vorteroj. Ankaŭ tiuj ne estas uzataj memstare.

Comment: Sed sufiksoj kiel anti-, -ik- kaj -it- ne estas produktaj. Oni ne povas formi novajn vortojn, nur ekzistas tiuj kiuj estas klasitaj en la vortaroj. Sed ja estas produkta la sufikso -i-, do kial ĝi estas la sola escepto? Produkta kaj nedisigebla?

Comment: Kial oni ne povas formi novajn vortojn per tiuj sufiksoj? Certe per _-it-_ (en la senco de inflamo) oni povas krei multajn novajn vortojn, ĉar oni povas aldoni ĝin al ĉiu ajn korpoparto, kreante vorton por obskuraj inflamoj, kiu ne aperas en vortaroj. Krome, mi pensas, ke ĉiuj vortoj, kreitaj per _-i-_, kiuj estas fakte uzataj, aperas en iu listo da landoj aŭ regionoj kaj en vortaroj. Fine, la signifo de _-uj-_ en mia respondo havas la saman signifon de _-i-_ en multaj kazoj, dum _ujo_ ne havas la signifon de lando, do certe _-i-_ ne estas la sola.

Answer (score 1):

Zamenhof origine intencis *(t.e. pure mia konjekto)*, ke ĉiu sufikso havu la formon *vokalo + minimume 1 konsonanto*.

Por landa sufikso `-ij'` eblus, kaj en slavaj lingvoj ekzistas kiel `ия`. Tamen li evitis la literkombinon `i+j` ĝenerale (fonetike pli bona), kaj uzis `-uj'`.

La sufikso `-i'` venis kiel (tiam neoficiala) reformo, pli *internacia*, tamen samtempe *lingve iom problema/nematura* (stacio, biologio, nenio).

Memstara uzo, kiel `eta, ujo`, ne taŭgas. Same `nenio` ne estas la lando de *nenoj*. Modere uzo `-i'` kiel en `rusianoj`.